# set visible false to button using reflection, is posible?

Tags: java, swing, reflection, jbutton

I just trying hide button through relfection.

```
Class userClass = Class.forName("vistas.RegistroPersonal");
Field f = userClass.getDeclaredField("btneliminar");
f.setAccessible(true);
f.setVisible(false);
```

is there a way... field does not have setVisible method...

Comment: Does this work? if not, do you get an error?

Comment: Did you even try before posting? `Field` has no `setVisible()` method.

Comment: Why do you have to use reflection for that? Don't you have any reference to those buttons?

Answer (score 0):

The setVisible() method on a Field does not exist, what you need to do is get a reference on the setVisible(boolean) Method (by its name & parameter types) and then invoke it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    TestApplication application = new TestApplication();
    Field field = TestApplication.class.getDeclaredField("button1");
    // This will allow us to access the button1 field even if it's private
    field.setAccessible(true);
    Method method = JButton.class.getMethod("setVisible", Boolean.TYPE);

    Object button = field.get(application);
    method.invoke(button, Boolean.FALSE);
}

public static class TestApplication {
    private JButton button1 = new JButton();
}
```

You need an instance of something to start with, if you start with the object owning your button then you can get its button via a Field and then invoke the Method. If you start with a button instance you can call the Method.

Please note that reflection seems like a convoluted way to do things here, the equivalent would be simply:

```
    TestApplication application = new TestApplication();
    application.button1.setVisible(false);
```

Comment: What I am trying is hide some buttons like "btn1" "btn2" that have been already created, how could I invoke their setVisible method

Comment: The normal way would be `btn1.setVisible(false)`

Answer (score 0):

To reflectivly call properties of a Java Bean such as Swing components, the recommended way is to use the [Introspector](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/beans/Introspector.html) class.

Some time ago, I've written a utility class, [BeanIntrospector](http://www.softsmithy.org/softsmithy-lib/lib/2.0/docs/site/apidocs/org/softsmithy/lib/beans/BeanIntrospector.html), to help working with beans and properties:

```
BeanIntrospector.setPropertyValue("visible", Boolean.FALSE, button, null);
```

The library is available from Maven Central:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.softsmithy.lib</groupId>
  <artifactId>softsmithy-lib-beans</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The library is Open Source and the code is available on GitHub:
https://github.com/SoftSmithy/softsmithy-lib